# Add jquery datepicker to asp repeater

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to add datepicker to the rows that would be generated by the asp repeater. But when i put in the id to the jquery it says that it is not declared.
asp:repeater used - 
*<%#(Container.DataItem).el_effdate#%>*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0sXU.png) Jquery used

Comment: You need to add script from code behind

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Not able to get you, what script do i need to add in the code behind ?

Comment: can you show your html code

Comment: Hi, so you want to have a look at my asp:repeater ?

Comment: plz show your html code (repeater and related javascript)

Comment: <td class="CSS_align_center">
  <%#(Container.DataItem).el_effdate#%>                                                <asp:Textbox ID="empdatepicker" runat="server" ClientIDMode="AutoID"></asp:Textbox> </td>

is my repeater control that is used, and the jquery is attached as a pic in my description

Comment: Please update your question with code. So that its with formatting.

Comment: As you said datepicker would be at row level hence multiple. i would suggest go with class instead of id

Comment: tried that now, it aint working :(